# Is there a way to run one job many times using GNU parallel?

Tags: gnu-parallel

I can see how easy it is to run a parallel job on multiple input but is there no other way to run the same job in parallel multiple times with putting the command in a file and repeating it many times?

```
parallel -j+0 ::: './dosomejob.sh'
```

but tell parallel to run that job x amount of times in parallel using the number of available cores?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typical. I spend ages trying to work this out and when I post a question, I think I actually worked it out.

```
parallel -j+0 './dosomejob.sh' ::: {1..10}
```

Is this the correct way to do this? Is there a better parallel way?

Comment: Rubber duck effect in action. :)

Comment: `-j+0` is default and can be left out.

Answer (score 14):

If you have less than 10 CPU threads:

```
parallel -N0 ./dosomejob.sh ::: {1..10}
```

`-N0` = insert 0 arguments.

If you want GNU Parallel to generate combinations, but you want all combinations repeated 5 times try:

```
parallel mycommand {1} {2} {3} {4} fixed_arg1 fixed_arg2 \
  :::: arg_file1.txt  arg_file2.txt \
  ::::+ arg_file3.txt  arg_file4.txt \
  ::: {1..5}
```

Comment: I don't quite get the `-N0`. Can it be omitted?

Comment: If you do that, you will pass argument 1 though 10 to `dosomejob.sh`. If you do not use that argument for anything, then yes you can omit `-N0`.

Comment: In my case, I have `parallel command :::: arg_file1.txt :::: arg_file2.txt ::::+ arg_file3.txt ::::+ arg_file4.txt ::: "fixed arg" ::: "fixed arg" ::: {1..5}`.

The `::: {1..5}` is supposed to repeat the command 5x. However, it breaks the command. I tried setting `-N6` to only consider the first 6 args and ignore the 1-5, but it still breaks. Am I missing something?

Comment: @CGFoX Yes. The {1} {2} {3} {4} in the example. Try using `--dry-run` to see what will actaully be run.

Comment: fish shell: `parallel -N0 ./dosomejob.sh ::: (seq 10)`